# Magento2.2.4 - Web Setup Wizard not working after upgade to Magento2.2.4

Tags: admin, magento2.2, magento-upgrade, web-setup-wizard, magento2.2.4

I upgrade Magento2.2.1 to Magento2.2.4.

I want to access `System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard` from admin panel.

When I click on *Web Setup Wizard*, then it displays the blank page.

And I also check `setup/index.php` is not called when this action is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it works

Go to public_html/app/etc/env.php and change the following code from

```
  'session' => [
'save' => 'db'
```

to

```
  'session' => [
'save' => 'files'
```